# T-SQL Help require for Pivoting multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table

```
City    Region      Zone    Passcode    SureveyBy   SureveyDone SureveyExpiry
Noida   Sector 62   East    1           ABC         Y           NULL
Noida   Sector 2    West    1           XYZ         N           6/10/2016
Delhi   CP          Cnt     10          ABC         N           10/10/2018
Delhi   KB          West    11          RST         Y           NULL
```

I need result in this format

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0DHV.png)

Comment: source table is 
CREATE TABLE Mytable
(
 City varchar(50),
 Region varchar(50),
 Zone varchar(10),
 Passcode varchar(50),
 SureveyBy varchar(20),
 SureveyDone varchar(5),
 SureveyExpiry date
)

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(max),@sql NVARCHAR(max)
    SELECT  @col=ISNULL(@col+',[','[')+t.SureveyBy+']' FROM dbo.myTable AS t GROUP BY t.SureveyBy
    PRINT @col
    SET @sql='
       SELECT * FROM dbo.myTable
       PIVOT(MAX(SureveyDone) FOR SureveyBy IN ('+@col+')) p'
    EXEC(@sql)
```